# How to convert and calculate datetime type yyyymm in varchar(6) using Tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 columns with datatype `varchar(6)` like this, format `yyyymm`. Now I want to `datediff` between them.
This is my solution,

```
select
    tblA, 
    tblB, 
    datediff(month, convert(datetime, tblA+'01', 120),convert(datetime, tblb+'01',120)+1 as count
from mytbl
```

any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that strings of the form YYYYMMDD can be converted directly to date values with no format needed.  So, a slightly simpler version is:

```
select tblA, tblB, 
       datediff(month, convert(date, tblA + '01'), convert(datetime, tblb+'01')+1 as cnt
from mytbl;
```

I should note that you *could* also do:

```
select ( (left(tblA, 4) * 12 + right(tblA, 2)) - 
         (left(tblB, 4) * 12 + right(tblB, 2))
       )
```

SQL Server will convert the strings to numbers in a numeric context.

Also, I find it strange that date columns are called `tblA` and `tblB`, but that is how the question is phrased.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well...

```
select dt1,dt2,
       datediff(month,concat(left(dt1, 4),'-',right(dt1, 2),'-01'),concat(left(dt2, 4),'-',right(dt2, 2),'-01')) dateDiff 
from mytbl
```

Comment: this will give difference between two column(monthwise) @Thành Phan

Comment: some text explaining this answer would improve it